# How to manage many rss feed on wordpress with mailchimp?

Tags: wordpress, rss, mailchimp, feed

I create a real estate site where it will be possible to filter properties by departments, through the creation of a taxonomy "Departments" (in Metropolitan France, 95 to create).

I'd like users could subscribe to receive new real estate offers by mail, by choosing the department(s) that interest them.

I use mailchimp to create my subscription forms but I wonder what is the best way to do it because for the moment I see only one solution:
On WordPress => create 95 rss feed templates by calling the taxonomy of the service corresponding to each model,
On Mailchimp => create 95 groups in an audience so that users can choose the department(s) when they register (it works well), create 95 differents campaigns for which we assign a different rss feed.

This seems to me tedious, for me the ideal would be to create a single RSS feed template on wordpress, and in the query to put a variable for the taxonomy, which varies depending on what department the user choose but I don't know how to link these two datas because the data "department" choosen by the user is data stored on Mailchimp. I don't know if I was very clear but I hope you can enlighten me!

Here is the query for the rss feed of the department 01 :

```
<?php 
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'real-estate',
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array (
            'taxonomy' => 'department',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => '01',
        )
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this won't work because of the way Mailchimp deals with RSS feeds. You cannot create a multifeed campaign containing all the new items in several feeds. Only one feed can... feed a campaign. And you cannot decide through groups which feeds would appear in this campaign. 
If you wanted the user to choose between your 95 areas, you would have to create 95 campaigns feeded by RSS. And if the the user checks, say, 2 areas... he would recieve 2 newsletters. I can imagine that it's not what you want.

Comment: Hi Serge and thank you for the answer. it is not the cleanest way but it is also the only way that I imagine, i'd prefere the user get one newsletter with the items according to the departments he ckecked.
Maybe should i use another service, but i tought Mailchimp was the most complete.

Comment: Any recommandations about another service wich allows multifeed ?

Comment: If I remember well, StackOverflow is not found of comments promoting services. And I can understand that. Could you join me in DM through Twitter for example? Or you can ask the same question in PowerUser part of StackOverFlow: https://superuser.com/